# My PC doesn't recognize my galaxy note 4. But it did when I purchased it.

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

My questions is just as titled.
When I got my new galaxy note 4 last month, I connected it to my PC and my PC showed my new note 4 so I was able to add video files.
But now  I connected my note 4 again to my PC to store all data from cell to PC cause it's full, my PC doesn't recognizes note 4. What should I do?

Comment: It might help if you could include some additional details: What Android version is running on the Note 4? Which OS are you using on your PC? Have you changed anything in the meantime (e.g. any updates made on the Note-4, or new installations on the PC)? Assuming you're using any version of Windows: Have you checked with your device-manager whether it shows any "conflicts" when the Note-4 is connected?

Comment: According to me the fix was to try different usb port

Comment: For me the solution was to use an **USB 2.0** port instead of a **3.0**. Sorry to put it here but I have not enough reputation to post an answer (though more than 7K on StackExchange!).

Answer (score 2):

2 options , both worked for Me when i had the Same issue:

If u use your fingerprintscanner , make sure you unlock your Phone After plugging it in

Second is to try Samsungs Software Kies and follow the programs instructions

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with my Note 4. Tried out various techniques/solutions found online such as installing drivers, activating developer options, using code *#0808#, resetting to factory settings etc. None worked. I eventually put the phone into download mode to attempt to root it (by powering off then pressing the home key, volume down button and power button simultaneously). I then pressed the volume down key to cancel the operation and restart the phone (without rooting it). Connected to my computer and now it's recognized.

Comment: I have the same problem but putting it in download mode and cancel did not help me. Neither the *#0808# settings.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the download mode thing and that didn't work. I was using some random micro usb cord that I had laying around. I decided to try the factory cord and my computer immediately recognized the phone was plugged into it and I was able to access everything on the device.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried a different micro usb cable and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

So I couldn't get my Note 4 or Galaxy Tab3 recognized by my computer recently.

The real crazy answer is that it had to do with my USB PORTS!  I had too many devices hooked up to the USB ports on my computer and there wasn't enough juice to communicate!  Once I disconnected a bunch of devices and tried various ports again, it worked!  It must not have been getting a full 5V I'm guessing?

As long as you are in the right mode and USING the RIGHT USB PORT, it should work!

1. If you have a Note 4, Dial `*#0808#` and make sure you are in "MTP + ADB Mode" and hit OK.  For a Galaxy Tab3, you need to hookup to a Windows 7 machine and then when you see the USB connection on the phone, bring down the top menu and select it and then make sure the phone is in "MTP mode" and not "PTP mode".
2. Using a *known* working USB data transfer cable (be aware that some cables only charge and don't transfer data), connect it to the phone and then keep trying DIFFERENT USB ports on your system until at least ONE of them works!  And if all of them fail, start DISCONNECTING your other USB devices from nearby ports and try again.  If even that doesn't solve the issue, try a POWERED USB HUB.

And if all of this fails to work, then you need to test your cable and eliminate it and finally in the last case scenario, you might be the unlucky one who has a damaged or defective phone micro usb port which only charges but doesn't communicate with a PC!  This has happened on one of my Galaxy S devices so it is possible but unlikely.

This will drive you nuts and cost you a lot of time unless you know this.  I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Typing *#0808# and enabling MTP + USB did it. That's totally stupid though, it should just be a setting in Settings, not some hidden code. Weird. Sanmsung, don't do that again, hiding useful features.

Answer (score 0):

I just waited there for a little long while, and eventually Windows started recognizing the phone. (After a couple of minutes of being plugged in.)

In the beginning the phone appeared to have no contents, but that was only because the phone was waiting for a confirmation from me as to whether I wanted to allow the PC to access the contents of the phone or not.  Once I agreed, the phone was not only recognized, but its contents were also accessible.

Answer (score -1):

If you connect the Samsung Galaxy Note 4 to your PC via USB, then it may happen that the device is not recognized as a media device. Thus it cannot be accessed the internal memory to copy images, music or videos. The Samsung Galaxy Note 4 isis only recognized by the PC as a camera module. If this situation applies with you, then we want to explain to you in this manual, how the Samsung Galaxy Note 4 is recognized correctly as a Media Device from your PC. 
For this purpose, the "USB debugging" option must be activated, which is located in the developer options of your Samsung Galaxy Note 4. If you do not already have unlocked the developer options on your Samsung Galaxy Note 4, then please follow these instructions. 
After the developer options are enabled on your smartphone, you can now tap the button "Developer Options" in the settings. You will get a list of different settings. In the section "Debugging" you will now find the "USB debugging" option. Set a tick in the checkbox to enable this feature on your Samsung Galaxy Note 4. If it is already enabled, disable and re-enable it with the data cable connected to the pc.
This mode starts automatically once if your smartphone is connected to the computer via USB cable and is responsible for that the Samsung Galaxy Note 4 is recognized as a media device by your computer. You can now access the internal memory of your smartphone and copy music, videos, photos etc. 
You know now how to enable USB Debugging on the Samsung Galaxy Note 4, which makes it possible to detect as a media device.

Comment: please improve formatting